# git push to nginx+git-http-backend : error: Cannot access URL http return code 22 fatal: git-http-push failed

Tags: git, nginx, fastcgi

I was configuring my git repos to serve over http in Ubuntu 14.04 (using nginx/1.4.6+git-http-backend+fastcgi:fcgiwrap 1.1.0-2). But caught with the following error.

```
# git push origin master
Username for 'http://server.com': git
Password for 'http://git@gittest.cloudthis.com': 
error: Cannot access URL http://server.com/rahul.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

My nginx site's configuration is as follows.

```
server {

    listen          80;
    server_name     server.com;
    root            /var/www/git/repos;

include /etc/nginx/fcgiwrap.conf; # Added as a support for cgi

auth_basic          "Welcome to my GIT repos";  # Added for Basic Auth +1
auth_basic_user_file    /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;

    location ~ /git(/.*) {
#    location /repos/ {

#client_max_body_size                   0;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL     true;
        fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT        /var/www/git/repos;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $uri;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_USER             $remote_user;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
}
```

I have my repos root dir as `/var/www/git/repos`. Under which I have initialized my bare repositories like `/var/www/git/repos/firstrepo.git/` using command `git --bare init firstrepo.git`

Git clone is working fine, but when I make changes and do `git push origin master` it gives error as

```
# touch newfile
# git add newfile
# git commit -m " commited "
[master 059714a]  commited
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 newfile
# git push origin master
Username for 'http://server.com': git
Password for 'http://git@server.com': 
error: Cannot access URL http://server.com/rahul.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Anybody have any idea What I'm doing wrong. Have also tried editing the .git/config file as said [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/256329/cannot-access-url-http-mywebsite-com-myproject-return-code-22-fatal-git-htt)

, but it didn't helped. The error remains intact

In my access.log

```
114.143.99.83 - - [14/Aug/2014:15:49:33 +0000] "GET /rahul.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 203 "-" "git/1.9.1"
114.143.99.83 - - [14/Aug/2014:15:49:36 +0000] "GET /rahul.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 203 "-" "git/1.9.1"
114.143.99.83 - git [14/Aug/2014:15:49:36 +0000] "GET /rahul.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 59 "-" "git/1.9.1"
114.143.99.83 - git [14/Aug/2014:15:49:36 +0000] "GET /rahul.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23 "-" "git/1.9.1"
114.143.99.83 - - [14/Aug/2014:15:49:37 +0000] "PROPFIND /rahul.git/ HTTP/1.1" 401 203 "-" "git/1.9.1"
```

In my error.log

```
2014/08/14 15:49:33 [error] 2872#0: *19 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 114.143.99.83, server: server.com, request: "GET /rahul.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1", host: "server.com"
2014/08/14 15:49:36 [error] 2872#0: *20 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 114.143.99.83, server: server.com, request: "GET /rahul.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1", host: "server.com"
2014/08/14 15:49:37 [error] 2872#0: *21 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 114.143.99.83, server: server.com, request: "PROPFIND /rahul.git/ HTTP/1.1", host: "server.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

As [described by Marcs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193391) you could solve your authentication problem by enabling the `receivepack` option, but this [disables the requirement for authentication](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html#_services). What you rather would want is to communicate to `git-http-backend` which user was successfully authenticated. This can be done by setting the `REMOTE_USER` FastCGI parameter to the [$remote_user Nginx variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_user).

```
server {
    ...
    location ... {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.htpasswd;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        ...
    }
}
```

Considering your current Nginx configuration, you might also run into a problem where the connection with fcgiwrap is prematurely closed, which has to do with that the [order of FastCGI parameters matter](https://serverfault.com/questions/512028/nginx-fcgiwrap-how-come-order-of-fastcgi-param-matters#512086). If `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` contains a definition for e.g. `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, it will not be overwritten with `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend` when using fcgiwrap.

Comment: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend discusses Git service  `receive-pack`.

Comment: Would you happen to know the specific commands that nginx requires to allow anonymous read access, but authenticated write access?

Comment: I'm going to try this, upvoting

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar setup as you have.

I think the problem is related the the *receivepack* option.

You should add this option to the config file of your bare repository

```
[http]
    receivepack = true
```

Or for a system-wide setting (as I did) insert the line above in: /etc/gitconfig

You can also use the config command like this for enabling a repository:

> git config --local http.receivepack true

Or to do it systemwide:

> git config --system http.receivepack true

Related to nginx you can also use the authentication in a location block instead of a server it makes the configuration more clean (IMO).